# Log4j configuration(Size Based) not working

Tags: java, log4j, rollingfileappender

I have my application for which the below entry is done in **Log4j** properties file.Size based rolling is not working for this application.
File does not rollover at 5 MB and the application keeps on logging and making it in GB. In one run approximately 6 MB of log is generated.The application runs multiple times a day.

Can someone help in pointing out where I am doing a mistake?

```
# SampleApp configuration
log4j.category.com.ibm.hmel.hwmmphdya=INFO, SampleApp  
log4j.additivity.com.ibm.hmel.hwmmphdya=false  
log4j.appender.SampleApp =org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.SampleApp.File=S:/FIH/LOG/SAMPLE_APP_01/SAMPLE_APP_01.log  
log4j.appender.SampleApp.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.SampleApp.layout.ConversionPattern=%-21d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n  

log4j.appender.SampleApp.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.SampleApp.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=S:/HIF/LOG/SAMPLE_APP_01  /SAMPLE_APP_01.log.%i.zip
log4j.appender.SampleApp.RollingPolicy.MinIndex=1
log4j.appender.SampleApp.RollingPolicy.MaxIndex=10
log4j.appender.SampleApp.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.SampleApp.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=5242880
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works for me

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, Roller

log4j.appender.Roller=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.maxIndex=13
log4j.appender.Roller.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  
log4j.appender.Roller.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=26214400
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=j_log_%i.log
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=j_log_0.log
log4j.appender.Roller.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Roller.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a unit to your size

```
MaxFileSize=5242880KB
```

Comment: Hi Christian,as per my understanding it should not have an effect.Still I had already tried using 5MB then also it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you're using lo4j companion extras. 
Please ensure you're using latest log4j.jar (version 1.2.17 worked for me and I've encountered problems with version 1.2.14).

I wrote simple test app to reproduce your problem:

```
package com.ibm.hmel.hwmmphdya;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Roller {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Roller.class);
    private final String FAKE_LOG_LINE = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Roller roller = new Roller();
        roller.logStuff();
    }

    private void logStuff() {
        for (;;) { // ugly loop
            logger.info(FAKE_LOG_LINE);
        }
    }
}
```

and placed following `log4j.properties` in classpath:

```
log4j.category.com.ibm.hmel.hwmmphdya=INFO, Roller
log4j.additivity.com.ibm.hmel.hwmmphdya=false
log4j.appender.Roller=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Roller.File=D:/FIH/SAMPLE_APP_01.log
log4j.appender.Roller.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Roller.layout.ConversionPattern=%-21d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=D:/FIH/SAMPLE_APP_01.log.%i.zip 
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.MinIndex=1 
log4j.appender.Roller.RollingPolicy.MaxIndex=10 
log4j.appender.Roller.TriggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.Roller.TriggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=5242880
```

My results are OK i think, theese are contents of my log output directory:

```
2013-02-27  09:30    <DIR>          .
2013-02-27  09:30    <DIR>          ..
2013-02-27  09:30         4 440 720 SAMPLE_APP_01.log
2013-02-27  09:30         5 242 920 SAMPLE_APP_01.log.1.zip
2013-02-27  09:30         5 242 920 SAMPLE_APP_01.log.2.zip
2013-02-27  09:30         5 242 920 SAMPLE_APP_01.log.3.zip
2013-02-27  09:30         5 242 920 SAMPLE_APP_01.log.4.zip
2013-02-27  09:30         5 242 920 SAMPLE_APP_01.log.5.zip
```

File size "5 242 920" is more or less what was configured.

You can troubleshoot your case further by providing `-Dlog4j.debug` system property.

**UPDATE:**
You may want to ensure companion extras lib (`apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar`) is present in classpath.

Comment: Thanks Pawel for your efforts.I have the same version i.e 1.2.17 and the apache log4j extra is also present.

Comment: I am surprised that the same thing is working for you and exactly how it is intended.I am trying to debug as you mentioned.

Comment: How do you provide the configuration properties? In my sample app I rely on automatic discovery of default "log4j.properties". Maybe in your case there are many same named properties files on classpath, and one of them lacks rolling appender?
I suppose it can be tricky if your application has some 3rd-party jar dependencies containing their own log4j.properties files or when it runs under control of app server (it can have separate logger configuration which is earlier on classpath than your custom config).
If you'll run with -Dlog4j.debug option, you'll see which log4j.properties is used.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you have included [apache-log4j-extras.jar](https://javalibs.com/artifact/log4j/apache-log4j-extras) and using [log4j-1.2.16.jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar) or at least above 2.17 version.
here is sample log4j.properties which can be used.

```
    #Worked with 2.17 version
    #make log files rotate based on size and zip old rotated
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, loggerId
    log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
    log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=5
    log4j.appender.loggerId.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
    log4j.appender.loggerId.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10000000
    log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=worker-%i.log.gz
    log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=worker.log
    log4j.appender.loggerId.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.loggerId.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

for more details on properties please check [here](http://2min2code.com/articles/log4j_intro/rolling_archiving_file_on_size_prop)