# My requirement is I want my application to create new file after reaching the limit and max backup index ? I am using log4j

Tags: log4j

My log4j.properties have below defined properties. I want my app to create a new file after reaching the maximum limit

```
log4j.logger.file=DEBUG, fileAppender
log4j.logger.error=DEBUG, errorAppender

log4j.additivity.file=false
log4j.additivity.admin=false

log4j.appender.fileAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileAppender.File=./log/PayHubUI.log
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.fileAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n

log4j.appender.errorAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.errorAppender.File=./log/PayHubUIerror.log 
log4j.appender.errorAppender.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.errorAppender.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.errorAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.errorAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Log4j configuration(Size Based) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105694/log4j-configurationsize-based-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using log4j-1.2.11 or earlier, then you will need to create the folder ./log yourself, else log4j will fail to create the log file. In later versions, log4j creates it for you. Once log file reach to maximum limit, current file rename and new file will be create.